# Why is there a high rate of answered questions?

Tags: discussion, public-beta

Does anyone else think that there is an amazingly high rate of answered questions on the main site?

Reviewing the question and answers, I am beginning to become concerned that people are voting answers as correct before they are fully vetted.

Could this be due to the high demands put on the commitment promise to Stack Exchange?

Comment: Isn't the whole point to get questions answered?

Answer (score 3):

Also, a question is considered answered if there are answers with upvotes. Joel talked about this [at his Google talk](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/joel-talks-about-stack-overflow-at-google/).

Answer (score 1):

I think it has more to do with the fact that there are over 100 active users on this site and we are generating less than 90 questions a day.  That means if those 100 users answer 2 questions a day we are getting at least 2 answers per question on average and that doesn't even include the other few hundred users who are answering less frequently.  As the community grows I think this will become less of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fresh site, so there's a better chance of new questions being answered. Plus I imagine the users are making an effort to answer questions to help build up this site.

Answer (score 1):

I think users are putting there effort into getting the top rankings similar to stackoverflow.com and there is good potential in for that if they contribute more from start.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, with a "answer rate" around [83%](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered), Web Apps is decidedly in the middle of the pack among the other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I'm only considering the list of sites at that link. The [tour] says there are currently 170 communities, which would seem to include those in open beta.